# How do I get a for loop to return the sum amount of specific things in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, count

I'm learning python 2 and I'm testing out what I know about for loops.

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == 'fizz':
            count = count + 1
            return count
fizz = [2, 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fIzZ', 6, 10, 'fizz', 'fizz']
print fizz_count(fizz)
```

above is something I made to test it, the idea is that every time the string 'fizz' is identified it add 1 to the variable *count*. As you can see, the string 'fizz' appears 4 times, so the number 4 should print. It doesn't.

Comment: Why would you return there?

Comment: Related [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2600191)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to return when the loop is finished. With the indentation you have, it returns as soon as the first `fizz` is found.

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == 'fizz':
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

But you're still not thinking [*pythonically*](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-cixvFNPgo1g/UvAH5geRpGI/AAAAAAAAAjM/q3GnGb4j-9E/s1600/Back+to+the+Future+6.jpg). `for` loops are for the birds. Let's use a generator expression.

```
 def fizz_count(x):
     return sum(1 for item in x if item == 'fizz')
```

Or heck, we can be lazy (smart) and just call a built-in function to do it for us.

```
def fizz_count(x):
    return x.count('fizz')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the return statement outside the loop. When python gets a return statement it exits the function immediately. So you want to return when your for loop is done, otherwise it wont finish the loop.
But you can also just set the print statement in the function, return has no use here